# vue create command: is webpack and loader configured automatically

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Is webpack configured automatically in the `vue create hello-world` generated project? Is any loader included by default? Like css-loader?

Comment: I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. you can run `vue-cli-service inspect` to check the webpack config. For more information [Inspecting the Project's Webpack Config](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config)